# I am changing a light switch and need your help

Tags: electrical, switch, circuit, wifi

Ok I am trying to install a Wifi switch 2 on 1 that I bought. If you see in picture 1 . The switch has 4 cables. A hot, a red one, and two load ones that goes to a light in the garage and by the entrance of the house. Two different circuits.

My issue is that the wifi light switch only has a line and two loads.

Can I put this

(top picture)Hot = line second picture
top load (top picture = load 1 second picture

then load 2 I have left the two button wires. Can i connect them together and put it with the load 2. Tight them up together.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Model # of the WiFi switch(es)? Actual pictures of devices and wires?

Comment: What part of the world are you located in? It is very country (and even when the wiring was installed) dependent what each wire color signifies.